# Generics with Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am trying to understand the following.

Say I have a class:

```
public sealed class UsageClass<TInstance> : IConsumer<TInstance>
    where TInstance: Lazy<SomeClass>
```

Now say I want to inherit the lazyclass

```
public class ImplementationClass : SomeClass
```

Now when I try to do

```
UsageClass<ImplementationClass> instance = new UsageClass<ImplementationClass>();
```

I would get an error.

This leave me with a couple of options:

wrap TInstance in Lazy, which I do not want to do. I want the objects in the class to always be lazy.

Try and make Implementation class inherit Lazy which I do not think will work. Will the child class then be lazy? and I think the compiler will still complain.

So my question is. How do I successfully Inherit Lazy for use with generic classes given the constraints above?

Comment: From a design perspective, I consider lazy instantiate to be the callers problem. I assume in this case you are trying to call `Lazy<T>` methods from inside your generic but do you have to?

Comment: maybe `public sealed class UsageClass<TInstance> : IConsumer<Lazy<TInstance>> where TInstance : SomeClass` ?

Comment: Hi Guys, Yes, since the design decision is that these objects are Always heavy on resources I want the base class to ENFORCE that the SomeClass objects are always Lazy and any object that inherits from SomeClass thus will be lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those interested I solved my issue by instead of making my classes Lazy I instead marked all my method properties inside the interface as lazy. This way I could still make my items of T and have lazy instantiation down the chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because it can't inherit the `SomeClass`. `TInstance` is statically defined to be `Lazy<SomeClass>`, not `Lazy<ImplementationClass>`. No generic there. You have to adjust your `UsageClass` to make the `Lazy` use the generic type instead to be statically typed (thanks to [Dennis_E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594485/dennis-e) for giving the right pointer):

```
public class UsageClass<TInstance> : IConsumer<Lazy<TInstance>>
                                     where TInstance : SomeClass
```

Then you can instantiate it like this:

```
UsageClass<ImplementationClass> instance = new UsageClass<ImplementationClass>();
```

Comment: Feels scrappy to use the same type name twice. Is there a way to avoid that?